# spring-security and jsf

Tags: spring-security

i am developing in JSF a Spring Security application.
the login form is fine.
however, when i try to retrieve the authentication object, in future code, i always get the authentication pricipal as anonymous.

i try to fetch is like this:
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HEy!

The problem was that i didn't add 
to the http in the security